# get first letter of words using sed

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, sed, command

I need a bash script that prints the first letter of a name. Example: Ruben Van Den Bosshe becomes RVDB or Ken Van de Wilde becomes KVdW

I want to use the sed command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's probably a neater way of doing this, but the following seems to work:

```
$ echo 'Ken Van de Wilde' | sed 's/\(\w\)\w*\( \|$\)/\1/g'
KVdW
$ echo 'Ruben Van Den Bosshe' | sed 's/\(\w\)\w*\( \|$\)/\1/g'
RVDB
```

To break down that regular expression a bit, it matches the following in turn:

- A letter of a word, captured in the first group: `\(\w\)`
- Zero or more letters of words: `\w*`
- And finally, either a space or the end of the line: `\( \|$\)`

That sequence is replaced with whatever was captured in the first group: `\1`

Comment: using the \w flag for white spaces is a GNU sed affectation, and won't work generally.

Comment: @Ahmed Masud: Fair enough, but the tags suggest that the the OP is using Linux, so I'd be very surprised if he / she weren't using GNU sed...

Answer (score 7):

```
$ echo 'Ken Van de Wilde' | sed 's/\B\w*//g;s/\s//g'
KVdW
```

Comment: +1 I think this is the first time I've seen the non-word-boundary marker used. Elegant.

Answer (score 4):

This should be compatible across all POSIX implementations of sed:

```
echo "Someone Is Watching" | sed 's/\([^[:space:]]\)[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*/\1/g'
SIW
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work for all implementations. POSIX sed doesn't require that \t be a tab, that's a GNU extension. So if you're not using GNU, you're more likely to get SIWc with \t being treated as just a t. You'd need an explicit tab to get it to work with a BSD-based sed, e.g. on Mac OS X.

Comment: ah right you are ... i made the same mistake that i was asking to avoid... bah :-) ...  Hard to inject that in here though. OKAY so I'll make it POSIX compliant ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Kev's answer can be improved slightly:

```
echo 'K Van de Wilde' | sed 's/\B.//g;s/\s//g'
```

or even shortened if all words are two characters or more to:

```
echo 'Ken Van de Wilde' | sed 's/\B.\s*//g'
```

If anyone knows how to extract the special case of a single letter word and incorporate it into the above regex I would be interested.