# getting the first letter of an filtered part in sed

Tags: sed

I have a filename e.g. `15736--1_brand-new-image.jpg`

My goal is to get the first letter after the `_` in this case the `b`.

With `s/\(.*\)\_\(.*\)$/\2/` I am able to extract `brand-new-image.jpg`

which is partly based on the info found on https://www.oncrashreboot.com/use-sed-to-split-path-into-filename-extension-and-directory

I've already found [get first letter of words using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859515/get-first-letter-of-words-using-sed) but fail to combine the two.

To validate my sed statement I've used https://sed.js.org/

How can I combina a new sed statement on the part I've filtered to get the first letter?

Comment: Alternatively, on a POSIX shell, you can try something like this: `file="15736--1_brand-new-image.jpg"; letter=$(printf %.1s "${file#*_}"); echo $letter`

Comment: @M.NejatAydin nice one. I came also up with a nodejs alternative: `node -e "console.log(process.argv[1].split('_')[1][0]);" 15736--1_brand-new-image.jpg`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With your shown samples could you please try following.

```
echo "15736--1_brand-new-image.jpg" | sed 's/[^_]*_\(.\).*/\1/'
```

***Explanation:*** Simply using substitution operation of `sed`, then looking till  1st occurrence of `_` then saving next 1 char into back reference and mentioning .* will cover everything after it, while substituting simply substituting everything with 1st back reference value which will be after 1st _ in this case its `b`.

***Explanation:*** Following is only for explanation purposes.

```
sed '            ##Starting sed program from here.
s/               ##using s to tell sed to perform substitution operation.
[^_]*_\(.\).*    ##using regex to match till 1st occurrence of _ then using back reference \(.\) to catch value in temp buffer memory here.
/\1/             ##Substituting whole line with 1st back reference value here which is b in this case.
'
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, for me still it quite hard to distinguish what part in the sed expression belongs to which part of the description.

Comment: @BasvanDijk, I have extended explanation for program, please do let me know in case you have any queries on same, cheers.

Comment: Great! What exactly are we substituting? It is not that we replace something right?

Comment: @BasvanDijk, From value `15736--1_brand-new-image.jpg` TO `b` we are replacing as per shown samples so when we are using back reference its happening on v[line value `15736--1_brand-new-image.jpg`, let me know if any queries on same, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `.` or `\w` could also match `_` in case there are 2 consecutive `__`

If you want to match the first word character without matching the `_` you could also use

```
echo "15736--1_brand-new-image.jpg" | sed 's/[^_]*_\([[:alnum:]]\).*/\1/'
```

Output

`b`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE 's/^[^_]*_[^[:alpha:]]*([[:alpha:]]).*/\1/p' file
```

Since this a filtering type operation use the `-n` option to print only when there is a positive match.

Match the first `_` from the start of the line and then discard any non-alpha characters until an alpha character and finally discard any other characters.

Print the result if there is a match.

N.B. Anchoring the match to the start of the line, prevents the result containing more than one character i.e. consider the string `123_456_abc` might otherwise result in `4` or `123_a`.